# A good example of a nonlinear symplectomorphism?

Tags: classical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, hamiltonian-formalism

What is a good example of a simple, physically useful *nonlinear* symplectomorphism $\kappa: \mathbb{R}^{2n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2n}$? I'm not much of a physicist, and all the examples I've worked have been purely mathematical and not connected to any physical problems. Obviously linear examples are well known and useful.

Actually, it would suffice if I could see some nice example of a nonlinear diffeomorphism (i.e. change of coordinates) $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ given by $x \mapsto y$, as one can then lift this diffeomorphism to a symplectomorphism by transforming the momenta via $p_y := (d\varphi^{-1})^{*}p_x$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the second paragraph(v1), haven't you basically answered your own question?

Comment: The Bloch equations, viewed as a Hamiltonian flow on $S^2$.  The symplectomorphism is rotation of the Bloch sphere.

Comment: @Qmechanic, well, I couldn't think of any good diffeomorphisms $\varphi$.

Comment: How about e.g. $\varphi(x,y,z):=(x(x^2+1),y,z)$?

Comment: Oh, I guess when I meant "physically useful", I meant that the coordinates were specifically used for some (hopefully easy-to-understand) physics problem. But I'll look at the Bloch equations and see if I can work out some mathematical results using them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Hamiltonian vector fields generate symplectomorphisms in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ (with the canonical symplectic form),one can pick any Hamiltonian,solve the Hamilton equations of motion to get a symplectomorphism. Since, a nonlinear symplectomorphism is sought, free particle and Harmonic oscillator Hamiltonians will not be good examples, as they give linear dependence on the initial conditions. But the Hydrogen atom Hamiltonian is a good example(for $\mathbb{R}^{12}$(two bodies in three dimensions subject to an inverse square attractive cental force)). The explicitely known solutions of its equations of motion are nonlinear symplectomorphisms.

Comment: Since you the OP asks about a physically useful transformation, you think it's useful for Hamilton-Jacobi formulation, right?

Comment: Thanks, I really like the Hydrogen atom example. Indeed, my trouble was that every time I wrote down a Hamiltonian for some physical system I knew about, I made it too simple so that the induced symplectomorphism was linear.